# Declaring vectors in a C++ header file

Tags: c++, vector

I am having some trouble with vector declarations in the header file of a C++ class I am making. My entire header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include "Message.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Person {

public:

 Person() {};
 Person(std::string emailAddress);

private:

 vector<Message> inbox;
 vector<std::string> contacts;
 std::string emailAddress;

};

#endif PERSON_H
```

My error occurs on the lines following the "private" declaration (where I declare my vectors). The error I am getting is C4430 - missing type specifier and and C2238 - unexpected tokens preceding ';'

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The answer has already been found and the problem was due to programmer negligence. Thanks for the feedback and sorry to post such a silly question on this site.

Comment: Don't you love how useless the compiler error is, after 5 years of C/C++ it's become almost second nature, but after a while using java it just strikes how useless the compiler erro is.

Comment: I don't think it was silly. I'm pretty new to C++ and I was making the same mistake, so this was just what I needed!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're missing the namespace:

```
std::vector
```

Comment: Arg, I feel like such a dunce. Thank you for pointing that out to me and sorry to everyone for clogging the site with such a silly question.

Comment: Compared to many questions here, it wasn't *that* silly :)  You get extra points for not putting `using namespace std;` :)

Comment: Hah, I'll take that. :P I'll give you the green check since you answered first.

Answer (score 15):

You need to put 'std::' before 'vector' just like you did with string.

Comment: Ah, of course. Gah, now I feel so foolish. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, adding the namespace did not work, however, I was missing the

```
#include <vector>;
```

Comment: Should be `#include <vector>` (with no semicolon)