# Why can't I declare a vector in a .h file?

Tags: c++

I have a tiny .h file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef BIGNUM_H
#define BIGNUM_H
#include <vector>

class bignum{

private:
    std::vector<int> num;
    num.resize(4);

};
#endif
```

I get the following error messages:

- excepted type speciefier
- this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

What am I missing?

Comment: The vector declaration is OK. The resize is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring vectors in a C++ header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230345/declaring-vectors-in-a-c-header-file)

Comment: @Mgetz, No, this is a different question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't call a method on a member variable inside your class declaration. If you want to resize the vector to 4 do so in the class constructor (or in another function but the constructor is by far the best place to do so).

In your cpp file you could do something like:

```
bignum::bignum() { num.resize(4); }
```

or:

```
bignum::bignum(): num(4) {}
```

The second one calls the vector constructor that takes a size argument. Or you can directly do it in your .h file:

```
class bignum{
    bignum(): num(4) {} // version 1
    bignum(): num() { num.resize(4); }  // version 2

private:
    std::vector<int> num;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot call `num.resize(4);` outside of a function. You could use your class' constructor, or a C++11 initialization at the point of declaration.

```
class bignum
{
private:
    std::vector<int> num = std::vector<int>(4); // C++11
};

class bignum
{
    bignum() : num(4) {} // C++03 and C++11
private:
    std::vector<int> num;
};
```

Comment: I got the error message: excepted a ; 

If I use the form std::vector<int> num{4};

Comment: @user2351645 do you have the relevant C++11 support? You need that, obviously.

Comment: It should create a vector with the size 4. As I know.

Comment: @user2351645, No, that creates a vector with one element - 4.

Comment: @user2351645 there was an error in my original answer. I fixed it in an edit.